# Parsing multiple XMLs in ZipInputStream

Tags: java, xml

I have an export feature, where I pack two XMLs into a ZIP file to be downloaded. In my UnitTest I want to assert that the export was correct so I read the ZIP file again and am trying to parse the XML. I am using a ZipInputStream and the following approach works:

```
InputStream result = testee.openStream();//here the ZIP and XMLs are created
try (var zis = new ZipInputStream(result)) {
    var firstEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
    assertNotNull(firstEntry);
    var nodesOne = getNodesByName(zis, "nodeOne");
    assertEquals(EXPECTED_NODE_ONE, nodesOne.getLength());
    
    var secondEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
    assertNotNull(secondEntry);
    var nodesTwo = getNodesByName(zis, "nodeTwo");
    assertEquals(EXPECTED_NODE_TWO, assertNotNull.getLength());
}

NodeList getNodesByName(ZipInputStream zis, String nodeName) {
    var xmlString = IOUtils.toString(zis);
    var is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
    var doc = DocumebtBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
}
```

But a more elegant way would be to replace the first two lines this in the `getNodesByName` with this:
`var is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(zis));`

This works for the first entry, but the second entry throws an exception as apparently the `InputStremReader` closes the `ZipInputStream` or reads it in full and not just the entry.
Is there a way to use streams that respect that it should only read the first entry?

Comment: What library are you using? The ZIP specifications has different versions and optional features.  Most libraries will work correctly when you ZIP a file all at one time.  When a ZIP is appended the optional parts of the ZIP specification (and versions) make unzipping complicated.  So not all unzip utilities implement all the options and work with all the versions.  Best to unzip using a good library like 7-zip.  The java unzip you are using may not be fully compatible with your zip file.

Comment: Everything is in Java and I am using the defaults `java.util.zip.*`, `javax.xml.parsers.*`, `org.xml.sax.*` and `org.w3c.dom.*`

Comment: Is the filename just the base name or the entire path?  The example I found on the net was the entire path was used to get the file.

Comment: You can [create an InputSource directly from an InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.xml/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)).  No need for IOUtils, no need for InputStreamReader or StringReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `IOUtils.toString(zis)` or `DocumentBUilder.parse(...)` is closing the `ZipInputStream`.

You could try this instead

```java
NodeList getNodesByName(ZipInputStream zis, String nodeName) {
    var streamWrapper = new java.io.FilterInputStream(zis) {
        @Override
        public void close() {
            // don't close the underlying stream
        }
    };
    var inputSource = new InputSource(streamWrapper);
    var doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
}
```

Comment: `IOUtils.toString(zis)` is the working one, so this doesn't close it, but if I use the stream directly for the `InputSource` is seems to close it. Either directly the `ZipInputStream` or what I tried with the `InputStreamReader`

Comment: See my update with `FilterInputStream` wrapper

Comment: Also, you should be calling `ZipInputStream.closeEntry()` once you have finished with each entry

Comment: Not necessarly needed, as .`ZipInputStream.extEntry()` closes any previous one and the try/with closes the whole `ZipInputStream` at the end. It is needed in the `ZipOutputStream` when you create ZIP file.

Comment: @lance-java there is no need to ever call `closeEntry()`. It does nothing - `next` closes the entry as does closing the zip entirely, of course. `closeEntry()`'s primary effect is that any calls to `read()` will return -1. Which is.. mostly useless. It doesn't recover _any_ resource whatsoever. "Should" is writing a cheque it can't cash in that sentence.